# Class reference member points to other member in same class

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-optimization

I am making a library that involves 3-D coordinates, and discovered that there are two names for the components of a 3-D angle: yaw-pitch-roll and heading-elevation-bank

So I made the following (done in c++11):

```
struct Angle {
    float heading;
    float elevation;
    float bank;
    float &yaw = heading;
    float &pitch = elevation;
    float &roll = bank;

     // Some Constructors (copy and assignment have to be made manually)
 }
```

Which has the benefit of keeping the notation equivalent between the two name-schemes.  For example:

```
Angle angle;
rotate(angle.yaw); // this is equivalent to rotate(angle.heading)
```

I was wondering if the compiler would figure out the references were unnecessary, or if it would keep the pointers in the structure.

Also, is there a better way to have two names for one member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if the compiler would figure out the references were unnecessary, or if it would keep the pointers in the structure.

In 99.9% of the cases, the pointers will be kept in the structure. I don't see a way for the compiler to exclude them over translation units. Esp since your syntax is invalid, and you'd have to initialize the references in the constructor, which could very well be hidden. So there would be no way for it to know which reference references which member.

There could be some performance overhead as well. For example:

```
  float x = a.elevation;
013F13E0  fld         dword ptr [ebp-18h] 
013F13E3  fstp        dword ptr [x] 
  float y = a.pitch;
013F13E6  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
013F13E9  fld         dword ptr [eax] 
013F13EB  fstp        dword ptr [y]
```

Indeed, internally, references act like pointers. So the extra `mov` makes up for dereferencing that pointer.

I wouldn't worry about it though, would instead care about the style. And having two member accounting for the same thing...just seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two different options. The first one would be pretty much what @Neal has already suggested, but including real C++ code:

```
struct Angle {
    float heading;
    float elevation;
    float bank;

    float& yaw() { return heading; }
    float& pitch() { return elevation; }
    float& roll() { return bank; }

    const float& yaw() const { return heading; }
    const float& pitch() const { return elevation; }
    const float& roll() const { return bank; }
};
```

The first set of methods returns non-const references, so it is possible to actually modify the struct's attributes through these methods. For instance:

```
Angle a{60, 45, 0};
a.roll() = 15;
```

The second set is used when you have a constant reference to an Angle and you just want to read the values in the struct. For instance:

```
void print_yaw(const Angle& a) {
    std::cout << "yaw=" << a.yaw() << std::endl;
}
```

I have checked the assembly code generated by GCC. Both directly using a struct attribute (e.g., `a.heading`) and using an alias method (e.g., `a.yaw()`) generate the same assembly code, so you do not pay any penalty for using the alias method.

The second way I can think of would be to use a totally different approach. Something like this:

```
enum Accessors { HEADING=0, ELEVATION, BANK };
enum AliasedAccessors { YAW=0, PITCH, ROLL };
typedef float Angle[3];

Angle a{60, 45, 0};
std::cout << a[HEADING] << " must be equal to " << a[YAW] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why make so many public variables?

You can just make some getters and setters (pseudocode):

```
struct Angle {
    float heading;
    float elevation;
    float bank;

    float& yaw() const  {
         return heading;
    }
    float& pitch() const  {
         return elevation;
    }
    float& roll() const  {
         return bank;
    }

    //etc...

    // Some Constructors (copy and assignment have to be made manually)
 }
```

Comment: I was basically writing the same thing :) But, shouldn't you return references to the actual attributes? Otherwise, they cannot be modified through the alternative name. Actually, two set of methods should be provided: `const float& yaw() const;` and `float& yaw();`. Then it will also work with references to a constant `Angle`.

Comment: @betabandido edit my code away ^_^ as I said it is `pseudocode`. Obviously it would not be completely like this ^_^ (and I do return references btw :-P)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore ahhh! **pseudocode** ___pseudocode___ _pseudocode_.